# What is the purpose of those "dual parasols"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Watching a live video stream from South Korea just now, I noticed these parasols in the background. They look like normal parasols but have two "layers". Like a hole in the top with another "smaller parasol" on top of the main one.

What is the purpose of this design? Could it really be just be for the visual look? Does it have some kind of practical purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

They are designed to let the hot air out that collects at the top.

Remember any hot fluid tends to rise, so allowing the hotter air to be vented helps cooling.

I there is a gentle breeze will it make much difference - well looks good...

Comment: Similar designs on golf umbrellas are marketed as a feature to improve wind resistance by letting air out, rather than it forcing the umbrella inside out.

Answer (score 4):

They are less likely to be flipped over, blown away or turned inside-out in strong winds, because the gap allows the air that would normally be trapped to escape. The second "cap" umbrella also directs some of the wind down and toward the sides, providing some counterforce at the same time. In addition, when smoking was still allowed in public, the gap meant the cigarette smoke didn't get trapped onder the umbrella in calm/windless weather.